# React routes working in dev but not in build on Apache – build issue or web server issue?

Tags: reactjs, apache

I have a react app with some simple routing, which works perfectly when running the dev server, but not when running from the build folder.

I have found similar, but NOT identical, issues online so far – I hope I'm not adding a duplicate question. If so my apologies and please direct me to the solution if possible.

The code is very straightforward, something like the following. As I mentioned it does already work over the dev server so I don't think the issue lies here.

```
<Router>
  <div className="App">
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/quotation">
        ...do quotation stuff...
      </Route>
      <Route path="/">
       ...do homepage stuff...
      </Route>
    </Switch>
   </div>
</Router>
```

I have added the .htaccess file as per the documentation:

```
Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

After deploying the build folder, accessing it directly works (in my case something like staging.example.com/frontend). The problem is trying to add a route, e.g. staging.example.com/frontend/quotation. Without the .htaccess file I get a 404, as expected. However with the .htaccess file in place it just serves me the home page, i.e. ignores the "/quotation" part.

EDIT: It works when I upload the contents of the build folder directly to the document root, e.g. staging.example.com following the example above. This solves the problem for now, but doesn't feel 100% satisfactory. I would guess the .htaccess file needs tweaking, but I'm unsure how. Alternatively could there be something in package.json like the "homepage" field?

Comment: have you tried placing a basename props on Router component? <Router basename="frontend"> note that this might not work on dev try it on production.

Comment: @Chanandrei no I haven't – is it possible to do this without knowing at build time the final URL of the deployed version? To give context, my dev version lives at "frontend", my staging somewhere else and probably the production will just live at root, but this is unknown.

Comment: @Chanandrei just tried this and had no effect

Comment: try again and add a leading slash <Router basename="/frontend">.. if you will deploy it in root directory no need for the basename prop but if it will live in the subdirectory you might need this and the homepage in package.json..

Comment: @Chanandrei I should have mentioned but I already tried both with and without leading slash and neither had any effect